# Are there Pastafarian myths which explain their religious attire?

Tags: myth-identification, pastafarianism

I'm thinking specifically of the [viral news stories](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEcQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telegraph.co.uk%2Fnews%2Fnewstopics%2Fhowaboutthat%2F8635624%2FPastafarian-wins-religious-freedom-right-to-wear-pasta-strainer-for-driving-licence.html&ei=Tl5OVbGlI8uz7gb_4oHoBw&usg=AFQjCNF2BtDX7nzSTu8MnpQ07Aa_oEcAQw&sig2=ctE_sDbHOP2T8FtzoOwNhQ&bvm=bv.92885102,d.ZGU) about various Pastafarians being allowed to wear a spaghetti strainer as religious headgear at work or in a driver's license photo.

Many religious outfits or articles of clothing have a stated purpose or even a whole story behind them, so I was wondering if Pastafarians have any stories about holy strainers (or other articles of unconventional clothing).

Comment: This is the last experimental question I wanted to ask before we go public. [Credit for the inspiration goes to Semaphore](https://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/140/are-fictional-mythologies-on-topic#comment258_143). I'm going to self-answer this one to prevent any (very understandable) assumptions that Pastafarian questions are inherently unanswerable. I'm hoping the votes on this can serve as a poll of whether or not Pastafarianism should be on-topic, assuming everyone tries as hard as I just did to make the question and answer decent.

Comment: I think you mean religious *sattire*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Strangely, the Pastafarian mythos doesn't seem to support the notion of strainers as religious headgear. The most prominent mention is the colander in the flood myth:

> He produced a great Colander of Goodness and He did collect water in
>   an enormous pot, which He heated; and He did drop in a heaping portion
>   of pasta and slowly simmer the sauce for so long that the original
>   human weren't even around anymore when He was finally ready to eat.
>   And He poured the spaghetti and water into the Colander of Goodness,
>   careful to make sure that the water went down the drain of His sink.
>   And as He was eating, He vacantly considered where the drain did
>   empty, and the FSM said, "Uh oh."
>
> <sub>Source: [The Gospel of the Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://www.klps.pl/pliki/gospel_fsm_eng.pdf) - The Flood</sub>

And no part of this story implies that wearing the great colander would be a particularly good thing.

Even the [Loose Canon](http://www.loose-canon.info/Loose-Canon-1st-Ed.pdf) has no more than a passing mention of someone wearing a "Holy Colander" and one Pastalm mentioning a strainer. So, it seems as though strainers are worn by Pastafarians solely because they're pasta-related and hemispherical.

However, there is a completely different kind of outfit that the mythos is extremely supportive of: **Pirate regalia**.

> ... it is disrespectful to teach our beliefs without wearing His
>   chosen outfit, which, of course, is full Pirate regalia.
>
> <sub>Source: [The Gospel of the Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://www.klps.pl/pliki/gospel_fsm_eng.pdf) - Pamphlets</sub>

There is no single reason why pirate regalia has this status, but the Gospel has a **lot** to say about pirates in general. Here are a few memorable examples:

> Pirates, as you know, are His Chosen People. Yet their numbers have
>   been shrinking ever since the 1800s. Consequently, we find that global
>   warming, earthquakes, hurricanes, and other natural disasters are a
>   direct result of the shrinking number of Pirates.
>
> <sub>Source: [The Gospel of the Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://www.klps.pl/pliki/gospel_fsm_eng.pdf) - The Spaghedeity</sub>

---

> ... we were created in His ideal image: that of the Pirate. Since then
>   we've only come to resemble other people's gods. ... It is important that we return to the ways of the Pirate before it's too
>   late.
>
> <sub>Source: [The Gospel of the Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://www.klps.pl/pliki/gospel_fsm_eng.pdf) - Unified Spaghetti Cheory</sub>